# Link jQuery file in html page in spring boot project

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot

I want to link Jquery file with html page but it gives me an error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)
the jQuery file is under static>js foler
and html is under templates folder
when I remove the @ComponentScan annotaion from main class it woks properly but spring boot doent create objects of classes defined class in contoller layer

**this is my html page**

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Register Page</h1>
</header>
<span th:text="${message}"></span>
<form th:action="@{register}" id="registerForm" method="post">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your first name"><br>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name"><br>
    <label for="email">User Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"><br>
    <label for="province">Province</label>
    <select name="province">
        <option value="takhar">Takhar</option>
        <option value="kunduz">Kunduz</option>
        <option value="kabul">Kabul</option>
        <option value="herat">Herat</option>
    </select>
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="number" name="phoneNumber">
    <button type="submit">register</button>
</form>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/validation.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this is jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#registerForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required",

            email: {
                required: true,
                email :true
            },
            phoneNumber:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 14
            },
            province: "required",
            password:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }

        },
        messages: {
            fistName: "please enter your first Name",
            lastName: "please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "please enter a password",
                minlength: "you need to enter at least 10 charecters"
            },
        email: {
            required: "please enter your email",
            email: "email is not in a proper format"
        },
        phoneNumber: {
            required: "please enter your phone",
            minlength: "phone number should be atleast 10 digits",
            mazlength: "phone number should not excede 14 digits"
        },
        province: "please enter your respective provicne"
        },

        formHandler : function(form){
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm confused, you have three `<script>` tags. The first one loads jQuery from a CDN and the third one loads jQuery from your local sources. Why do you have two? Which of these is not working (or perhaps it's the combination)? What `@ComponentScan` are you referring to (normally you don't need any)? Can you share a minimal example demonstrating the issue? Right now you have an entire form and validation that is perhaps not related to the issue. For now, I'm voting to close this question for the reasons I just mentioned.

Comment: first link is for jQuery library the second link is for validation library and third is my writen code to validate th form when I run application browser console gives this error(validation.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)

Comment: Usually when you get such unexpected token, it means that there's a HTML page served rather than a JS page. This could be a 404 page or something. If you open http://localhost:8080/js/validation.js (change the port/context path if you have any), what do you see?

Comment: localhost:8080/js/validation.js it opens the index page of aplication

Comment: That's strange (it's not the default behaviour), do you have any special mappings (controller or config wise)?

Comment: no special controller